# How to initialize and format external SSD in commandline?

Tags: macos, partition, diskutil

How can an external disk be initialized, partitioned and formatted in macos Sonoma commandline?

I tried checking out my external drive with the command `diskutil list`:

```sh
...
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                                                   *2.0 TB     disk2
```

I can see that there is no partition or file system, I verified this with `diskutil info disk2`:

```sh
...
Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
File System:               None
...
```

I just need one big partition formatted as APFS, I guess APFS should be the detault these days. I know I could have done it with Disk Utility, but I am looking to do this on the commandline.

Comment: Use the`diskutil eraseDisk apfs "name" gpt disk2` command. You can substitute `name` with your desired name for the APFS volume which will be created.

Comment: yep thats exactly what I needed.

Comment: I suppose I should post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command given below

```
diskutil eraseDisk apfs "name" gpt disk2
```

You can substitute name with your desired name for the APFS volume which will be created.